# logging out of UX.stackexchange

Tags: discussion

I can't see a 'logout' button anywhere in the ux.stackexchange.com page. Advice was 'click on the 'StackExchange' logo (top left) to get the dropdown, but at present this just gets you a small screen of information about the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: This is an interesting question. Since it can be generalized to 'How to design an intuitive way to log out of a system?'. But in this case it is more 'How do I log out of THIS system?'. As such, it belongs on ux.meta.stackexchange, since it is particular to how we perform this action only here.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here is the logout link over here.
you may be not observe some hidden things that is not so noticeable often.
the logout link is not nested inside the stack-exchange logo. its inside a hamburger menu icon which is just look like Stack exchange logo . check bellow the difference between the logo and its menu icon.

if you are about to logout then you can use the link 
https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/logout

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/logout

This is the way to logout of here.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can find it here.
I also don't get why they designed it like this.

Comment: May be they want to discourage log out action

Answer (score 0):

The logo is actually on top right corner, next to question mark icon, achievements icon etc.